# how to run neo4j source code and support remote debug?

Tags: neo4j

I want to use driver to connect the neo4j server, and debug the code of server part.

I have add the "dbms.jvm.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" in neo4j.conf, and then how to run the source code?

Answer (score 0):

After [configuring the server for remote debugging](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/server-debugging/), just run the server using the appropriate instructions for the [server's environment](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/installation/).